# Show Parent Menu children in sidebar

Tags: 8

I want to explain this as simple as possible...

I have a main navigation placed into the main_navigation block in my site
and I want to add a sidebar menu if the CURRENT main_navigation page has
child menus...

For example:

1. My main navigation is: Home | About | Services | Blog | Contact
   Us
2. I added **Request Quote** page/form as a child of Contact Us
3. so when I am in Contact Us page, I want to show **Request Quote** in the
   sidebar but don't show it if I am in About or Services

I saw this question but can't duplicate it

[Get menu link siblings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183201/get-menu-link-siblings)

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solved the issue by doing a few things:

1. I downloaded & enabled this module: https://github.com/studgate/expanded_menu_block, a temporary Drupal 8 port of menu_block
2. Placing a new block in the left_sidebar region, I selected the main navigation menu
3. configure the block to have 'Initial menu level 3' and 'unlimited' menu levels to display
4. Clear cache and make sure your child menus are showing properly in the sidebar

[image]
If other child menu items are showing in the sidebar, go to Edit Menu page and edit each Parent Main Navigation menu and uncheck 'Show As Expanded'

If there is even an easier way, just comment...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Menu Block module, create a new Menu Block using the Primary Navigation, starting at Level 2.

This will only show the children of the current parent menu item you are in.

Comment: Menu Block module is not available for Drupal 8... I already created a secondary_menu block with starting at level 2 but it's showing for all main active menus...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the tiny 8 tag on the post. Haven't worked with D8 yet, sorry.

Comment: that's ok, you're trying to help, I know how to do it in drupal 7 but a little harder in 8...

Answer (score 0):

Add this block
core\modules\system\src\Plugin\Block\SystemMenuBlock.php

if ($level > 1) {
   if (count($parameters->activeTrail) >= $level) {
       // Active trail array is child-first. Reverse it, and pull the new menu
      // root based on the parent of the configured start level.

```
   $menu_trail_ids = array_reverse(array_values($parameters->activeTrail));
    $menu_root = $menu_trail_ids[$level - 1];

    $parameters->setRoot($menu_root)->setMinDepth(1);
    if ($depth > 0) {
      $parameters->setMaxDepth(min($level - 1 + $depth - 1, $this->menuTree->maxDepth()));
    }
  }

  else {
    return array();
  }
}
```

Configure level 2 or above level in block layout.
[image]