# Display selected menu parent with children in sidebar

Tags: navigation

I have a menu  build with taxonomy menu structured like this :

Agenda

- agenda1
- agenda2

News

- News1
- News2

Access

- Access1
- Access2

My main navigation is like this (no children): Agenda | News | Access

What i want to do is , when i click Agenda for example ,i would like to dispay in agenda page in the side bar the block menu corresponding with children

Agenda

- Agenda1
- Agenda2

  I have read many forum on this but not able to get it working :

[Show Parent Menu children in sidebar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204349/show-parent-menu-children-in-sidebar)
[Get menu link siblings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183201/get-menu-link-siblings)
[How to display a block with menu child items programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224593/how-to-display-a-block-with-menu-child-items-programmatically?rq=1)

I try Menu bloc module to do this but when i set Initial visibility level = 1 , all the menu with children is displaying , but i would like just display the selected menu with his children

When i set Initial visibility level > 1 nothing is display

Any help is welcome

Comment: I have remarked that this is not working  when i create the menu with taxonomy menu module ,  but if i do not use taxonomy menu module to create my menu , it's working if i set Initial visibility level = 1 in menu block placement

Answer (score 0):

I get it working by using this module : Hierarchical Taxonomy Menu https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_taxonomy_menu

Thanks