# Get parent menu item of a current node

Tags: 8

I'm trying to get the parent menu item of node I am currently on:

```
$node_id = // some id
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
$parent = $menu_link->getParent();
```

but for some reason it always fails with this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getParent() on array
```

When I inspect `$menu_link` I can clearly see it is there:

[image]

Also the method of `getParent()` seems to be correct: [Docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkInterface.php/interface/MenuLinkInterface/9.0.x)

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183201/get-menu-link-siblings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to reset the collection first, as the `::loadLinksByRoute()` annotation states that it returns an array of `MenuLinkInterfaces[]`.

See `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Menu/MenuLinkManagerInterface.php`:

```
  /**
   * Loads multiple plugin instances based on route.
   *
   * @param string $route_name
   *   The route name.
   * @param array $route_parameters
   *   (optional) The route parameters. Defaults to an empty array.
   * @param string $menu_name
   *   (optional) Restricts the found links to just those in the named menu.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkInterface[]
   *   An array of instances keyed by plugin ID.
   */
  public function loadLinksByRoute($route_name, array $route_parameters = [], $menu_name = NULL);
```

So do something like:

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkManagerInterface $menu_link_manager */
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_links = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
// Reset collection by retrieving the first item.
$menu_link = reset($menu_links);
// Now call the parent method.
$parent = $menu_link->getParent();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, appreciate it. Now I'm getting a new error: `Error: Call to a member function getParent() on bool`. Do you have a second idea?

Comment: Seems like it has to do with that `reset()` returns `false` if the array is empty.

Comment: I think you are right about that. I guess you first need to double check that it is indeed returning an array of objects and not an empty array.

Comment: got it working, thanks for the answer, the `reset()` helped.